# Trying to Export data in mongodb but got this Error ?Expected a nested document representing

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, deserialization

Expected a nested document representing the serialized form of a Rootobject value, but found a value of type Array instead?
C# Code:
My guess is that I should write a custom serializer for that class but I couldn't find any useful example in the MONGODB .NET DRIVER Manual.
I'm working with C# MongoDB driver

string inputFileName = @"1546346582.07002.json"; // initialize to the input file

```
        IMongoCollection<Rootobject> coll = database.GetCollection<Rootobject>("BB");
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(inputFileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                using (var jsonReader = new MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonReader(line))
                {
                    var context = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(jsonReader);
                    var document = coll.DocumentSerializer.Deserialize(context);
                    coll.InsertOne(document);
                }
            }
        }
```

```
 public class Rootobject
    {
        [BsonElement ("Property1")]
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }


    }




 public class Class1
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement ("ID")]
        public string account { get; set; }
        [BsonElement ("Account")]
        public string accuser { get; set; }
        [BsonElement ("Accuser")]
        public string bookedby { get; set; }
        [BsonElement ("BookedBy")]
        public bool changed { get; set; }
        [BsonElement ("Changed")]
}




  public class Fromtovia
    {
        public string info { get; set; }
        [BsonElement ("Info")]
        public string address { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Address")]
        public float lat { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Latitude")]
        public float lon { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("longitude")]
        public string postcode { get; set; }
    }

But I couldn't find anything Useful.
```

Comment: Is the jsonReader returning anything?  Is context or document null?  I do not think the json serialization is going to work on one line of file at a time.  Use ReadAllText() and then put that into your serialization code.

Comment: json reader returning null,

Comment: It is the json that is the issue.  As I said use ReadAllText().